# run terminal command but don't show output via python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, command-line, terminal

**I tried this**

```
a = subprocess.run(['apt download timeshhhh'],stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
```

**but this shows:**

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

E: Unable to locate package timeshhhh
```

**I want only:**

```
E: Unable to locate package timeshhhh
```

**what to do?**

Comment: Split on newline and capture the last item.

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match the text.  **"don't show output via python"** is not the same as only wanting to see the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the `stderr` output, which you didn't redirect. You can redirect it to `DEVNULL` if you don't want to see it.

```
a = subprocess.run(['apt download timeshhhh'],stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.DEVNULL, shell = True)
```

Comment: Not 100% that a `WARNING` output would be on `stderr`.

Comment: If it's not coming from the pipe, it presumably is.